# How to show more information than filename in Photoshop's opened tabs

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

The above image shows tabs of opened files in photoshop.

I'm making icons of android app for multiple resolution support.
Some of you may know that Android treats same filename in different folders named `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-ldpi` to support multiple resolution.

I'd like to put a kind of tag or title in order to indicate which file is belonged to each folder, for example `[ldpi] ic_menu_template.psd`.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I'm not aware of a native way to show more info. Just an idea, you could use mini bridge to keep your files organized inside the program...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible. The tab names are hard coded into the internal application framework.